# htaccess redirect pattern not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, prestashop-1.5

I am using the following code in my htaccess file

`Redirect 301 /([0-9]{1,2})+_([A-Za-z])$ /brand/$1-$2`

to redirect the following type of URL pattern :

`www.mywebsite.com/{ID}_{BrandName}`

So basically I have to redirect

`www.mywebsite.com/{ID}_{BrandName} to www.mywebsite.com/brand/{ID}-{BrandName}`.

For example : Redirect 301 to `www.mywebsite.com/5_TestBrand to www.mywebsite.com/brand/5-TestBrand`.

Please suggest.

Below is the htaccess code which is not working :

`Redirect 301 /([0-9]{1,2})+_([A-Za-z])$ /brand/$1-$2`

Please Guide.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use regex and captured groups in `Redirect` directive. Use `RediectMatch` instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]+)_([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /brand/$1-$2
```

Comment: Thanks Sir..I was expecting you :-). Still The code is not working.

This is what I used 1) RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]+)+_([A-Za-z])/?$ /brand/$1-$2

2)RedirectMatch 301 ^([0-9]+)_([A-Za-z])?$ /brand/$1-$2

Comment: I have to redirect www.mysite.com/5_action TO www.mysite.com/brand/5-action

Comment: Sir, your solution worked ! But any suggestion to redirect www.mysite.com/6_action-kids TO www.mysite.com/brand/6-action-kids..

Comment: This one worked tooo..I have simply added another redirect match RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]+)_([A-Za-z]+)-([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /brand/$1-$2-$3  and it worked ! Thanks :):):)

Comment: Glad that you sorted out your issue, really well done.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the rewrite engine is on at the top of your htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Then, shouldn't it look something more like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)_([A-Za-z])$ /$1/brand/$2-$3 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

Or perhaps:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)_([A-Za-z])$ /brand/$1-$2 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

Something like that, I always have to fiddle around with the htaccess to get it perfect.

Comment: Thanks Kevin but none of the code is working :(

I have to Redirect www.mywebsite.com/5_TestBrand to www.mywebsite.com/brand/5-TestBrand